# How do you create a car part group?

Tags: car-mechanic-simulator-2018

I am in the process of replacing a front suspension which includes a front shock absorber, front shock absorber cap, and a front spring. Those items are all purchased separately in the computer, but when I attempt to replace them, I only get the option of installing the old broken group of parts that are already assembled. I can't find a way to combine those three parts into a group in order to install it onto the car. Once I sold the old group of broken parts, now the option just says "No items to work with"[image]

When I look in my inventory, there is a section called "Groups", and it shows the tire/rim groups, as they were removed:

[image]

Clicking anywhere on that screen doesn't give any kind of menu to create a new group, and none of the workstations I have available in my garage give the option to create groups of parts.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sooner did I submit this question than I turned around and saw a tool in the shop that I'd not seen before since it was partially hidden behind a column. It's the "Spring Puller" and it's used to create and separate groups.

[image]

Once you select this item, you can select items to combine into a group. You just need to use the radial menu again and select to remove the part from the spring puller, then it appears in your inventory.

[image]

I'm going to leave the question up, since the tutorial wasn't very helpful in my opinion, and there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation about this game that I could find useful.

**Update**: In the screenshot with the spring puller, on the right side is a tire machine too -- this is what is used, like the spring puller, to create "groups" of tires and rims. Side note: I found out that every time you attach a tire to a rim, it needs to be balanced in the machine next to that before you an attach it to the car.